# What kind of a matrix has a unitary diagonalizing matrix?

Tags: inverse, transformation, diagonalization

Suppose $D = P^{-1} A P$. When is $P$ unitary?

In other words, what kind of a matrix $A$ should be, such that $D=P^{\dagger}AP$? i.e. what are the conditions a matrix must have to be able to diagonalize it using unitary matrices?

Comment: Normal. $A A^* = A^* A$.

Comment: @copper.hat, is that an "iff" condition?

Comment: Yes indeed. The significant part of the result is that a normal matrix is unitarily diagonalisable, as if a matrix is unitarily diagonalisable, then it is straightforward to show that it is normal (since all diagonal matrices are normal).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Any normal matrix ($AA^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}A$) is unitarily diagonalisable.

In particular, any hermitian matrix is unitarily diagonalisable, since $H=H^{\dagger}$.